# Pandas: Error tokenizing data--when using glob.glob

Tags: python, pandas, concatenation, glob

I am using the following code to concatenate several files (candidate master files) I have downloaded  from [here](http://fec.gov/finance/disclosure/ftpdet.shtml#a2011_2012); but they can also be found here:

```
https://github.com/108michael/ms_thesis/blob/master/cn06.txt
https://github.com/108michael/ms_thesis/blob/master/cn08.txt
https://github.com/108michael/ms_thesis/blob/master/cn10.txt
https://github.com/108michael/ms_thesis/blob/master/cn12.txt
https://github.com/108michael/ms_thesis/blob/master/cn14.txt

import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import glob


df = pd.concat((pd.read_csv(f, header=None, names=['feccandid','candname',\
'party','date', 'state', 'chamber', 'district', 'incumb.challeng', \
'cand_status', '1', '2','3','4', '5', '6'  ], usecols=['feccandid', \
'party', 'date', 'state', 'chamber'])for f in glob.glob\
        ('/home/jayaramdas/anaconda3/Thesis/FEC/cn_data/cn**.txt')))
```

I am getting the following error:

```
CParserError: Error tokenizing data. C error: Expected 2 fields in line 58, saw 4
```

Does anyone have a clue on this?

Comment: When you use `read_csv` on one file, does the dataframe look as expected? You may need to pass `delimiter = "|"` to the `read_csv` function.

Comment: I just tried reading with just one file and using ?`sep='|'; and then after your comment ^ I tried using `delimiter = '|'` and it worked fine. I tried the whole operation again and Problem Solved! Thanks for the clue!°

Comment: Glad it worked! I added it as an answer in case anyone else has the same problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default delimiter for `pd.read_csv` is the comma `,`. Since all of your candidates have names listed in the format `Last, First`, pandas reads two columns: everything before the comma and everything after. In one of the files, there are additional commas, leading pandas to assume that there are more columns. That's the parser error.

To use `|` as the delimiter instead of `,`, just change your code to use the keyword `delimiter="|"` or `sep="|"`. From the [docs](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_csv.html), we see that delimiter and sep are aliases of the same keyword.

New code:

```
df = pd.concat((pd.read_csv(f, header=None, delimiter="|", names=['feccandid','candname',\
'party','date', 'state', 'chamber', 'district', 'incumb.challeng', \
'cand_status', '1', '2','3','4', '5', '6'  ], usecols=['feccandid', \
'party', 'date', 'state', 'chamber'])for f in glob.glob\
    ('/home/jayaramdas/anaconda3/Thesis/FEC/cn_data/cn**.txt')))
```

Answer (score 1):

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import glob


df = pd.concat((pd.read_csv(f, header=None, names=['feccandid','candname', \
    'party','date', 'state', 'chamber', 'district', 'incumb.challeng', \
    'cand_status', '1', '2','3','4', '5', '6'  ],sep='|', \
    usecols=['feccandid', 'party', 'date', 'state', 'chamber'] \
    )for f in glob.glob\
    (/home/jayaramdas/anaconda3/Thesis/FEC/cn_data/cn**.txt')))
print len(df)
```